# LoadUserProfile->Unhandled crash (how to prevent?)

Tags: vb.net, interop

I have a Windows service running as SYSTEM. Sometimes, on some computers (this cannot be reproduced easily) the whole process dies when I call LoadUserProfile.

I am talking about a .NET application, here is the stack trace:

```
Application: MyProcess.exe

Framework Version: v4.0.30319

Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException

Stack:

   at MyAssembly.MyClass.LoadUserProfile(IntPtr, PROFILEINFO ByRef)
```

I am not sure this problem can be solved but I would like to be able to handle this instead of my process dying. I am using try..catch as well as capturing "Unhandled exceptions" in my application.

Here is more information about how I use the function:

```
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
        <System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(False)>
    Public Structure PROFILEINFO
        Public dwSize As Integer
        Public dwFlags As Integer
        Public lpUserName As String
        Public lpProfilePath As String
        Public lpDefaultPath As String
        Public lpServerName As String
        Public lpPolicyPath As String
        Public hProfile As IntPtr
    End Structure

Declare Auto Function LoadUserProfile Lib "userenv" Alias "LoadUserProfile" (ByVal hToken As IntPtr, ByRef lpProfileInfo As PROFILEINFO) As Boolean

                    Dim UserProfile As New PROFILEINFO
                    UserProfile.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(UserProfile)
                    UserProfile.lpUserName = strUserName 'strDomain & "\" & strUserName
                    UserProfile.dwFlags = 1
                    Try
                        If LoadUserProfile(token, UserProfile) Then
                            impResult.ProfileLoaded = True
                            hProfile = UserProfile.hProfile
                            IsProfileLoaded = True
                        Else
                            impResult.ErrorOccured = True
                            Dim intErrorCode As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
                            impResult.ErrorString = "Profile was not loaded - error code: " & intErrorCode.ToString
                            Throw New Win32Exception(intErrorCode)
                        End If
                    Catch ex As System.AccessViolationException
                        impResult.ErrorOccured = True
                        impResult.ErrorString = ex.ToString
                    End Try
```

Any idea how to tackle this? Thanks!

Comment: after adding `OPTION STRICT`, I would start [with studying PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/userenv/LoadUserProfile.html)